# tmux gives no current session each time after enter a session on macOS

Tags: tmux

I'm running macOS Sierra and have tmux 2.4 installed. Once upon a time, I found I couldn't paste via "p" in vim, so I added below into my .tmux.conf

```
set -g default-command 'reattach-to-user-namespace $SHELL --login'
```

However, the vim issue solved, but it leads another issue: each time I launch a tmux session from Shell, it will throw a "no current session" error. Although, it doesn't impact daily use much, but it's annoying. I tried to remove that configuration and did a reload, unfortunately, I couldn't get rid of that message.

My tmux.conf is:

```
# remap prefix from 'C-b' to 'C-a'
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-a
bind-key C-a send-prefix

# split panes using | and -
bind | split-window -h
bind - split-window -v
unbind '"'
unbind %

# switch panes using Alt-arrow without prefix
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
bind -n M-Up select-pane -U
bind -n M-Down select-pane -D

# Enable mouse mode (tmux 2.1 and above)
set -g mouse on

# reload config file (C-a r)
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf; display-message "Config reloaded..."

set -g default-command 'reattach-to-user-namespace $SHELL --login'

# status bar
set -g status-left-length 50
set -g status-left '[#{client_session}] [#{session_attached}] '
set -g status-justify centre
```